# How to modify key value pair in a nested Object Array generated dynamically

Tags: javascript, json

I have below Array..

```
[{
    "text": "test",
    "subheader": "Production",
    "enabled": false,
    "nodes": [{
        "text": "test",
        "subheader": "JP",
        "enabled": false,
        "nodes": [{
            "text": "test",
            "subheader": "test Operations",
            "enabled": true,
            "nodes": [{
                "text": "test",
                "subheader": "test Operations",
                "enabled": false,
                "nodes": [{
                    "text": "test",
                    "subheader": "test Operations",
                    "enabled": true
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        "text": "test",
        "subheader": "Planning JP",
        "enabled": false,
        "nodes": [{
            "text": "test",
            "subheader": "test Operations",
            "enabled": false,
            "nodes": [{
                "text": "test",
                "subheader": "test Operations",
                "enabled": true
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        "text": "test",
        "subheader": "india",
        "enabled": false
    }, {
        "text": "test",
        "subheader": "Sales Office, South East Japan",
        "enabled": false
    }, {
        "text": "test",
        "subheader": "Partner Sales JP",
        "enabled": false
    }]
}]
```

If you see the this array block.

```
"nodes": [{
            "text": "test",
            "subheader": "test Operations",
            "enabled": true
        }]
```

The above array code block will get added dynamically and it may add n number of times. Now I just want to change **enabled true to false** in the entire array

Can someone please help me code to loop and change the enabled value to false in complete Structure?

Comment: 1. Parse the JSON. 2. Modify the JS array by recursively iterating into the objects (search that in google or here). 3. stringify into JSON

Answer (score 1):

I know it is a poor question but here is a real simple way to change ALL enabled:false to true

```js
let arr = [{ "text": "test", "subheader": "Production", "enabled": false, "nodes": [{ "text": "test", "subheader": "JP", "enabled": false, "nodes": [{ "text": "test", "subheader": "test Operations", "enabled": true, "nodes": [{ "text": "test", "subheader": "test Operations", "enabled": false, "nodes": [{ "text": "test", "subheader": "test Operations", "enabled": true }] }] }] }, { "text": "test", "subheader": "Planning JP", "enabled": false, "nodes": [{ "text": "test", "subheader": "test Operations", "enabled": false, "nodes": [{ "text": "test", "subheader": "test Operations", "enabled": true }] }] }, { "text": "test", "subheader": "india", "enabled": false }, { "text": "test", "subheader": "Sales Office, South East Japan", "enabled": false }, { "text": "test", "subheader": "Partner Sales JP", "enabled": false }] }]

arr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr).replace(/"enabled"\:false/g,'"enabled":true'))
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the map function:

```
let data={
     "nodes": [{
            "text": "test",
            "subheader": "test Operations",
            "enabled": true
        }]
 }


  data.nodes.map((node)=>Object.assign(node,{enabled:false}))
```

Comment: `change the enabled value to false in complete Structure`